# How do I get rid of little black border around page?

Tags: css

[image: Black edge around page]

I have a little black border around my page, just on the left and top. I can get rid of it, but I want the background to be stretched. If I make it so it's not stretched, it goes away. I don't want that. When I make it not stretched, it repeats instead. I want it to do both. Here's my CSS.

```css
body {
    background: url(background.png);
    background-width:100%;
    background-height:100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Without the `background-size: 100%;` I have the border there, but it is also the cause of the repeating background.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information.  Can you show us an example that also shows the image?

Comment: I am running on localhost and can't really portforward my site. I am very new to Stack Overflow, and could use a little help. Can you tell me if there's a way to upload images?

Answer (score 0):

Crop Image canvas to get rid of borders

Comment: If you dont have graphical redactor you can use online service for that,
i.e.: http://imageresize.org/

Comment: Why are you using an image if it is one color only ?
Just use
 background:#34FE95;

Comment: It's not one color

Comment: Then you can use background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out, I needed to do the linear-gradient with width:100vh;.